# How to get selected row value in the KendoUI without javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following kendoUI grid:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>List of SSF Pension Subscription</h4>
    <p>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
            .Name("Grid")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border: 0;" })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(s => s.PensionNumber);
                columns.Bound(s => s.FirstName);
                columns.Bound(s => s.FatherName);
                columns.Bound(s => s.GrandName);
                columns.Bound(s => s.FamilyName);
                columns.Bound(s => s.BankLookup.BankName);
            })

            .Sortable()
            .Navigatable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server()
                .Model(model => model.Id(s => s.MemberID)))
        )
    </p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { id =  ???????}, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</div>
```

I want to get the selected row id after clicking on the edit button and pass that id to the action method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you want the information?  Do you want to fire an event when the row is selected or report the selected row id when pressing a submit button.

Comment: I want passing selected row id to another page via @Html.ActionLink

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that *without*  javascript.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks, According to the above code,  How can I do that using JS ?

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif it would be something like this: http://dojo.telerik.com/eZASu

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif if you add a column in your grid with the button `Edit` you could use templates droping the javascript.